# Форма обратной связи. Не приходит письмо на почту

Tags: php, javascript

js

```
$("#b_form").submit(function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    e.preventDefault;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
        self.trigger("reset"); 
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
    return false;
});
```

php

```
<?php 
$recepient = "<hidden>@gmail.com"; 
$sitename = "mysite"; 
$name = trim($_POST["name"]); 
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nEmail: $email"; 
$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\""; 
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient"); 
?>
```

Comment: Проверьте, а php файл получает данные?

Comment: Солидарен с Shilgen, сначала проверьте свой mail.php

Comment: `<?php

    $recepient = "<hidden>@gmail.com";
    $sitename = "mysite";

    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);

    $message = "Имя: $name \nEmail: $email";

    $pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";

    mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain;     charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
    ?>`

Comment: Так у вас данные-то из формы попадают в скрипт mail.php?

Comment: Да, проверил. Данные приходят.

Comment: Если у вас в функцию `mail(...)` попадают данные, то надо смотреть что возвращает эта самая функция `mail(...)`. Она возвращает либо `TRUE`  (письмо отправлено) либо `FALSE` ( ошибка отправки). Если `FALSE`, то копайте в сторону настроек сервера, скорее всего в сторону *sendmail*